# Handling exceptions in TThread.Execute to make it uninterruptible

Tags: multithreading, delphi, exception

There is a multi-threaded app, which runs 24/7. A correct disposal of resources as well as a proper exceptions handling (including `EAccessViolation`) are key factors.

I am a little bit stuck on understanding how to correctly nest exception-handling blocks within a thread functions.

Among `TMyThread.Execute` there are two helper-function:

`function LoadHtml(const AUrl: sting): string` - a simple wrapper for `TIdHTTP.Get()`

`function ParsePage(const Id: string): TOffers` - a parser/DB-updater function

`Execute` starts querying database for the initial recordset of IDs. Then it starts a `while not rs.Eof do` loop where calls `ParsePage` which is a main *processor*.

`ParsePage` loads HTML (care of `LoadHtml`), then performs some string parsing operations and finally updates database.

Here is a code structure: (details omitted for brevity)

```
{Wrapper-function to load HTML page}
function TMyThread.LoadHtml(const AUrl: string): string;
var
  Response: TStringStream;
  HTTP: TIdHTTP;
begin
  Result := '';
  Response := TStringStream.Create('');
  try
    try
      HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
      HTTP.ReadTimeout := 10000;
      HTTP.Response.KeepAlive := false;
      try
        HTTP.Get(AUrl, Response);
        if HTTP.ResponseCode = 200 then Result := Response.DataString;
      finally
        HTTP.Free;
      end;
    finally
      Response.Free;
    end;
  except
    //This code will run only on exception and *after* freeing all resources?
    on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
      if E.ErrorCode = 404 then
        raise EMyOwnHTTPNotFoundError.Create('Page not found');
    else
      HandleErrorAndLogItToDB(E.Class);
  end;
end;

{Loads HTML, processes it and updates DB}
function TMyThread.ParsePage(const Id: string): TOffers;
var
  RawHTML: string;
  Offer: TOffer; //a simple record to store key offer details;
begin
  Result := TOffers.Create;
  try {top-level try..except block}
    try {Critical request. If it fails I want to move}
      RawHTML := LoadHtml('http://onlinetrade.com/offer.html?id=' + Id);
    except
      on E: EMyOwnHTTPNotFoundError do {Defined in function LoadHtml()}
        //Update DB: product does not exist.
      else
        HandleErrorAndLogItToDB(E.Class);
      end;
    end;
    try
      //Preform some basing string operations on RawHTML
    except
      on E: Exception do HandleErrorAndLogItToDB(E.Class);
    end;
    try {Iterate through some blocks of data and put them in the Offers: TList}
      for i := 0 to N do
      begin
        //Set up TOffer record
        Result.Add(Offer);
      end
    finally
      FreeAndNil(Offer);
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      HandleErrorAndLogItToDB(E.Class);
      FreeAndNil(Result);
      raise; {does this return control to Execute?}
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Now `Execute`:

```
procedure TMyThread.Execute;
var
  j: Integer;
  s: string;
  Offers: TOffers; {Is a simple TList to store a collection of TOffer (record)}
begin
  inherited;
  CoInitialize(nil); {ADO is in da house}
  try {top-level try..except block}
    try {nested try..finally to call CoUninitialize}
      try {A critical operation which sources all further operations}
        rs := AdoQuery('GetSomeRecords ' + IntToStr(SomeId));
      except
        on E: Exception do
        begin
          HandleErrorAndLogItToDB(E.Class);
          Exit; {DB-query error means no reason to continue}
        end;
      end;
      while not rs.EOF do
      begin
        try //a loop top-level try..except handler
          Offers := ParsePage(rs.Fields['Id'].Value);
          try //nested resource freeer
            begin
              try //nested try..except to handle DB queries
                for j := 0 to N do with Offers.Items[j] do
                  AdoUpdateDB; //Update DB
                Synchronize(UpdateProgressBar);
              except
                on E: Exception do
                begin
                  HandleErrorAndLogItToDB(E.Class);
                  Continue; //as suggested
                  raise; //as suggested
                end;
              end;
              rs.MoveNext;
            end;
          finally
            FreeAndNil(Offers);
          end;
        except
          on E: Exception do HandleErrorAndLogItToDB(E.Class);
        end;
      end; //end while..do loop
      Synchronize(ResetProgressBar);
    finally
      CoUnitialize;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      //Make everything possible to keep the thread running. No matter of:
      //- HTTP/404 - Not Found exceptions (which I handle)
      //- UpdateDatabase fails
      //- String operation exceptions
      //If anything critical occurs, Execute() shall just go to the next offer
      //even if the current one is not properly processed.
    end;
end;
```

Looking at this code I think, I try to handle too many exceptions which I probably do not need to handle, just passing them to the most outer `try..except` handler in `Execute`. There are just a couple of exceptions I really need to handle: initial database query and `EMyOwnHTTPNotFoundError` (to set a flag that the offer doesn't exist). I read somewhere a suggestion not to explicitly chase for exception handling unless you really need it...

However it is very important that the thread keeps on running no matter of which exceptions are thrown inside/outside any code blocks. The idea is to completely ignore exceptions and never break either `while..do` loop or stop the thread. At the same time, correctly disposing resources is also a must.

I would be grateful for any suggestions/comments on how to improve this code.

Comment: You should ask yourself why you are raising AVs in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no good way to "handle" an access violation, or really *any* exception that does not indicate a specific condition that your code has already planned for.  (For example, a File Not Found exception can be handled in a good way if you can simply tell the user to ask for another file.)

If an exception is raised as the result of a bug, it means something is happening in your code that you did not plan for.  Your code rests on a bunch of assumptions about things going right, things working as planned, and when an unexpected exception is raised, it means that *those assumptions no longer necessarily hold*.  The best thing to do at that point is produce an error report to send back to you, **and then shut down as quickly as possible.**

Why?  Because one of your assumptions that may no longer hold is that "critical data is in a valid, non-corrupted state."  If the program keeps going, blindly following the assumption that all its data is good and then acting on it, it can turn a small problem into a much bigger one very, very quickly.

I completely understand the desire to make the program keep on going no matter what, but unfortunately it fundamentally conflicts with reality.  The only sane thing to do when you get an unhandled exception--especially something like an access violation that can *only* be the result of buggy code of some variety--is to produce an error report and shut down.

If downtime is a Very Bad Thing, you could have something in place to make sure to start back up again as quickly as possible.  This will keep you running, but it will reset your invariants (fundamental assumptions) and clear out the corrupt data.  But for the love of all that is binary, **shut the program down, and do it right away.**

Then take the error report and fix your bug.

Comment: But it looks as he's doing the LoadHTML/ParsePage *per thread*. If the results of these threads are not dependant on each other, maybe he can get away with terminating the thread (and not processing that file again). That still leaves catastrophical errors like the database falling away.